# Ghost lines when moving an image after zooming or dragging using cropperjs

Tags: angular, typescript, cropperjs

I am using zoom in and zoom out feature by using npm library croppers. But the problem is the whenever image is dragged it leave some image lines. Anyone can help resolving it?

[This is the screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7U66.png)

I have applied this css:

```
cropper img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
```

Comment: I have attached the screenshot, Please check the red box. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution:

By applying this CSS to cropper img,

```
cropper img {
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
height: auto;
backface-visibility: hidden
```

}

these lines will disappear